# Pyinstaller - app without needed library on macOS

Tags: python, pandas, macos, pyinstaller

I've prepared python script (using pycharm in both OS, projects with venv, pyinstaller cpmmand run in pycharm terminal) which begins with
'import pandas' and want to make macOS application.

In windows everything works fine after creating app with 'pyinstaller --onefile main.py' command.

In macOS, script works but app not. Tried
`pyinstaller --onefile main.py` and `pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=pandas main.py` but in both ways, app says:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "main.py", line 1, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
> [26064] Failed to execute script main
> logout
> "

Why pyinstaller makes my app without pandas? How to make it take pandas?
Thanks for all responses.

Comment: Has the Pycharm terminal the correct venv (containing pandas)?